# Can't serve external CSS File in Go webapp

Tags: css, go

I recently started learning go and I want to develop a simple website. However I can't figure out how to use a external CSS File for this Website.

This is my directory structure:

```
./
  main.go
  static/
    css/
      home.css
  templates/
    home.html
```

Here is my main.go file:

```
package main

import (
        "html/template"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)

        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
        http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

        log.Println("Listening on :8080...")
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        renderTemplate(w, "home")
}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string) {
        t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/" + tmpl + ".html")
        if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
        }
        err = t.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
}
```

And in home.html I added this in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
```

When debugging in the browser it seems that the file is found, but there's an error with the MIME type: [Browser Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POrMP.png)

I thought that this two lines would solve that, but apparently it doesn't:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Content-Type header in the response correctly. Without the content type, most browsers will not execute the css. Something like the following should work, but this is essentially just a sketch:

```
 http.HandleFunc("/static/",func(wr http.ResponseWriter,req *http.Request) {
    // Determine mime type based on the URL
    if req.URL.Path.HasSuffix(".css") {
      wr.Header().Set("Content-Type","text/css")
    } 
    http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs)).ServeHTTP(wr,req)
 })
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick response. I had to use `if strings.HasSuffix(r.URL.String(), ".css") {}` and also change the css link in the html to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/home.css"`. Now it works! Thanks.