# Why is my CSS file being sent as type "text/plain" when it's set as "text/css"?

Tags: html, css, http, go

I've found multiple posts about this and tried each relevant solution with no success.

Folder Structure:

```
-example
    -style
         style.css
    -views
         index.html
     main.go
```

I run my "main.go" file (which looks like this):

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var t *template.Template

func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
}

func main() {
    t = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("example/views/*.html"))

    http.HandleFunc("/", IndexHandler)

    http.Handle("/style/", http.StripPrefix("/style/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("style"))))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

And I open "localhost:8000" in firefox where I see that the html is being [displayed as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4keQ.png) (html looks like this):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>please work</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However the "style.css" file is not being applied.

```
h1{
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

When inspecting the page console it shows these two errors:

```
GEThttp://localhost:8000/style/style.css
```

```
The resource from “http://localhost:8000/style/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
```

In the html file I declared the stylesheet type as "text/css" so I don't know why it's being sent as "text/plain".

when I change the `href="style/style.css"` in "index.html" to `href="../style/style.css"` and use firefox to open just the html file then the CSS is displayed perfectly. However when being displayed by "main.go" there is no CSS. I'm 95% sure the former method `href="style/style.css"` is the correct one when using static files in Go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't serve external CSS File in Go webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176818/cant-serve-external-css-file-in-go-webapp). In short: the HTTP header Content-Type needs to be set properly too.

Comment: @crackLot are you executing the program from the `example` directory? Or are you executing it from a different directory? The reason this is relevant is because you are using a *relative* path in `http.Dir`, for example if you run the program from the `example` directory, and the `style` is its immediate child, then `http.Dir("style")` should point to the directory that you expect, however, if you run the program from anywhere else, then that **will not be the case**.

Comment: @mkopriva This solved my problem. Thank you so much I was about to have a mental breakdown!

Comment: @crackLot also note that thwd is right, you should always use an absolute path in your asset links inside the html. If you use relative paths then those relative paths, before the assets are requested from the server, will be prefixed with the current url's path. e.g. if you're on `localhost:8080/` then `href="style/style.css"` will result in a request to `/style/style.css`, but if you navigate to `localhost:8080/some/other/page` then `href="style/style.css"` will result in a request to `/some/other/page/style/style.css`.